# Hibernating printer to minimize attacks via Wi-Fi Direct

Tags: wifi

I upgraded a dinosaur multi-function printer (MFP) to a less
prehistoric model [1].  "How convenient!" I thought of the Wi-Fi
Direct, considering that I'm (lucky enough to be) working from home on
a tiny desk and could do with one less cable.  Convenience and
security, however, are diametric opposites, and I had a lot of
difficulty finding out about the real-world security risks of Wi-Fi
Direct, to which I was new.  I was thankful for the short-lived bliss
of ignorance.

Then I came across a [useful
article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/wifi-direct-insecure).  Drat.
And no surprise.  The doubly sad thing is that *The Point of Entry*
section names the manufacturer of my new MFP and perfectly describes
the vulnerability to brute force attack due to the short pass code.

**From a practical standpoint, can the vulnerability be mostly
ameliorated by keeping the MFP hibernated when not in use?**  I rarely
use the device, but when I do, it could be for up to a few hours,
though often less.  I live pretty high up in a high rise, so even
though I may have nosy neighbours, there will be no drive-by's.

[This page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reaver-wps) gives
an idea of how vulnerable Wi-Fi Protected Setup is.
In order for someone to exploit the vulnerability, however, they would have to
be living within 100m of me and be poised to initiate a brute force
attach the moment that I bring the device out of hibernation.  This
is assuming that it is not vulnerable during hibernation.  It also
assumes that the detection and initiation of attack is not automated.

If an attack succeeds, I'm not sure how vulnerable the laptop itself
is.  It is the partner device in the Wi-Fi Direct connection.

**NOTES**

[1] While the specific products are secondary to the point of the
question, the dinosaur MFP was HP PSC 750 and the less prehistoric MFP
is the HP LaserJet Pro MFP M28w.

Comment: An aside, can't you disable WiFi Direct and hook the printer up to your existing WiFi network?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'll definitely look into it.  It would be my first time setting up a network service.  Thanks.

Comment: what is the risk; wasting your paper? Unless someone can get into your apt, there's no real carrot, and even then the carrot is just free printing; hardly worth risking a B+E charge. That article is typical security scare theater. Point out that someone can connect, then spookily claim w/o proof that they somehow get full access to the machine and connections. It also said "Bluetooth has been around since 1994", when the first device to use it came out in 1999.

Comment: @dandavis: I wanted to dismiss the risk based on an outlook similar to that in your comment. The problem might be the detailed info that can be stolen, e.g., if you print out tax returns, health info, mortgage contracts, etc. The depth of personal information is significant. Of course, the vetting and identifying of valuable info would need to be automated for this to be worthwhile. Since I don't "work" in the commodification of stolen identities, I don't know how that world works. I also did not know whether that is the only risk, or whether intruders can bridge into the connecting laptop.

Comment: Could you use a cross-over ethernet cable (coloured red by convention) to connect directly to the printer when you use it, and then unplug and pack this away once finished? (You can hard-code each device to be on the same non-routable subnet.)

Comment: Spoke too soon - I see this device is USB and WiFi only.

Comment: I could use a USB, though I haven't yet tried to print.  I'm trying to see if there is a way to retain the convenience of having one less cable in my rat's nest of a microscopic desk when working at home.

Comment: did you find out about the non-direct wifi?

Comment: No.  I haven't had a chance.